# Bash, Issues with ordering array of string by there suffix

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, sorting

and running into something strange here,

So say I have an array variable of strings called Names, such as

```
_billy_2 _bobby_1 _william_3
```

I am trying to order them descending by their numeric value,

I'm doing so by using something like:

```
sortNames=($( printf '%s\n' "${names[@]}" | sort -k3 -t'_' -r))
```

This works fine and well

However, If I have an array such as:

```
_billy_115 _bobby_3 _william_4
```

This will print out:

```
_william_4 _bobby_3 _billy_115
```

Rather than:

```
_billy_115 _william_4 _bobby_3
```

Any ideas as to why? or what's a good approach to solve this issue? cheers !

Comment: You forgot `-n` (numeric).

Answer (score 0):

Let's reduce the input to contain simply the following in a `file`

```
115
3
4
```

When we run `sort -r file` (`-r` reverse sort) on this file, we get

```
bash$ sort -r file
4
3
115
```

However, we are expecting

```
115
4
3
```

Why is this so?

`sort` by default does *character collating sequence*.  Meaning, it compares the first character between lines, then second character, then third...
For example, `101` will be sorted before `12`, because `0` is before `2`.

This default sorting mechanism is not always what we wanted - sometimes we want numeric comparison, meaning, `12` before `101`, because `12` is smaller than `101`.

Like in our example, we wanted to compare numerically `3`, `4`, `115` as numbers.

To do numeric comparison, there are quite a few directives that GNU sort provides, some as follows:

```
       -g, --general-numeric-sort
              compare according to general numerical value

       -n, --numeric-sort
              compare according to string numerical value
```

`-g` is floating point comparison, `-n` is integer comparison. Floating point comparison is slower than integer comparison.

In order to get the sort order we are expecting (reverse numeric order), we can run the sort with the `-r` and `-n` directive as follows, which would gives us the order we want:

```
bash$ sort -r -n file
115
4
3
```

To apply to your original command, it would then looks like this

```
sortNames=($( printf '%s\n' "${names[@]}" | sort -k3 -t'_' -r -n ))
```

Which should gives

```
_billy_115 _william_4 _bobby_3
```

Reference https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html

Exercises:
What about comparing negative numbers? Or comparing numbers with + sign?
Or comparing numbers using comma for thousands? Or comparing numbers from different locale/character set?

Comment: ahh yeah that makes complete sense, thanks !!